# Opentelemetry with .NET autoinstrumentation - logs not replacing placeholders

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, open-telemetry, grafana-loki, open-telemetry-collector

I am using open telemetry with loki service (and grafana to display the logs). The body of the log contains placeholders, and under "attributes" you can see the fields. Is there any way to also display the log with the values replaced?
i.e.:

```
{
  "body": "End processing HTTP request after {ElapsedMilliseconds}ms - {StatusCode}",
  "attributes": {
    "ElapsedMilliseconds": 489.8766,
    "StatusCode": 200
  }
}
```

I'd like to have something like:

```
{
  "enrichedBody": "End processing HTTP request after 489.8766ms - 200",
  "body": "End processing HTTP request after {ElapsedMilliseconds}ms - {StatusCode}",
  "attributes": {
    "ElapsedMilliseconds": 489.8766,
    "StatusCode": 200
  }
}
```

We are using auto instrumentation with .NET Core, so there is no code in the application. I've setup open telemetry with loki, and grafana to display it.
I've tried different processors (batch, using attributes and resources...) but no luck so far.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Very interesting question. I think this might be possible with some clever templating. Basically iterating through attributes [with `range`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/template_functions/#fromjson) and manually substituting them into message.

Comment: interesting, I didn't know about range. I'll take a look, thanks!

Comment: In that case I'd recommend also get more familiar with general concepts of go templates, on which grafana templating is based.

Answer (score 1):

The described behavior is expected. You can force an exporter to do what you expect by setting `OTEL_DOTNET_AUTO_LOGS_INCLUDE_FORMATTED_MESSAGE`
ref: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet-instrumentation/blob/v1.4.0/docs/config.md#logs-exporter.

Under the hood, this environmental variable sets this property https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/core-1.7.0/docs/logs/customizing-the-sdk/README.md?plain=1#L27-L31